# Not work jQuery for for input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, keyup

Main code:

```
var clone = div.clone();
clone.attr('id', sabad_kala_id);
$('.content').append(clone);
$('div#'+sabad_kala_id).replaceWith('<tr id='+sabad_kala_id+'><td width="50"><a class="del_kala" id='+sabad_kala_id+'><img src="images/delete.png" alt="delete" /></a></td><td width="50">1.</td><td width="388">'+title+'</td><td width="80" clas="mm"><input class="count" type="text" value='+count+' /></td><td width="100">'+price+' $</td><td width="120">'+price_count+' $</td></tr>');
```

and this code run perfect
after append and replace, user can edit `input.count` in table and below code have run :

```
('input.count').keyup(function(e){

        alert(test);
    });
```

but this code does not work.

Comment: Are you missing a $ in the second example?

Comment: correct : alert('test');

Comment: $ is character and no problem this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are creating the element dynamically, you should delegate the event:

```
$(document).on('keyup', 'input.count', function(e){
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: could you explain reason plz ?

Comment: The input.count elements don't exist when you are trying to add an event handler to them. The approach undefined has outlined results in the document listening for keyup events on anything that matches the selector criteria

Comment: not work , error : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'

Comment: @Mohammad Because you are using old version of jQuery, you should use newer version of jQuery or use `delegate` or `live` method.

Comment: i use this version : jquery.min.js and jquery-1.1.3.1.min.js , update it ?!

Comment: @Mohammad Yes, definitely, that version is too much old.

Answer (score -1):

The code doesn't work because the handler keyup is executed when the page loads and won't respond to any objects added later. Use <strike>`$(".count").live('keyup', function(){})`</strike> to fix your code.

Correction: use `$(document).on("keyup", ".count", null, function(){ // code here})` since jQuery 1.7 (see http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: I would not use live() as it was deprecated since jQuery 1.7. Try @undefined's answer instead.

Comment: ah my mistake, my knowledge seems to be outdated. Will fix the answer :)